# Button with sound OnClick causing NullPointerException

Tags: java, android, xml, nullpointerexception

I am new to java and I am creating a button that once you press, you get a sound-simple stuff.
My code is this inside MainActivity:

```
ImageButton one = (ImageButton) new Button(R.id.imageButton); //error here
final MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.pears);
one.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

    public void onClick(View v) {
        mp.start();
    }
});
```

I get an error "in Button cannot be applied to int" but my variable is not type of int but a Button type. Also a fatal error with a NullPointerException.I looked up NullPointerException and seems like you get the error when an object is not created. But I am creating an object of ImageButton...
Any advice? Thanks

Here is the onCreate method:

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.grid_item); //layout with ImageButton id imageButton

        mTitle = mDrawerTitle = getTitle();

        // load slide menu items
        navMenuTitles = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.nav_drawer_items);

        // nav drawer icons from resources
        navMenuIcons = getResources()
                .obtainTypedArray(R.array.nav_drawer_icons);

        mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        mDrawerList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_slidermenu);

        navDrawerItems = new ArrayList<NavDrawerItem>();

        // adding nav drawer items to array
        // Home
        navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[0], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(0, -1)));
        // Find People
        navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[1], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(1, -1)));

        // Recycle the typed array
        navMenuIcons.recycle();

        mDrawerList.setOnItemClickListener(new SlideMenuClickListener());

        // setting the nav drawer list adapter
        adapter = new NavDrawerListAdapter(getApplicationContext(),
                navDrawerItems);
        mDrawerList.setAdapter(adapter);

        // enabling action bar app icon and behaving it as toggle button
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);

        mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, mDrawerLayout,
                R.drawable.ic_drawer, //nav menu toggle icon
                R.string.app_name, // nav drawer open - description for accessibility
                R.string.app_name // nav drawer close - description for accessibility
        ) {
            public void onDrawerClosed(View view) {
                //getSupportActionBar().setTitle(mTitle);
                // calling onPrepareOptionsMenu() to show action bar icons
                invalidateOptionsMenu();
            }

            public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
                getSupportActionBar().setTitle(mDrawerTitle);
                // calling onPrepareOptionsMenu() to hide action bar icons
                invalidateOptionsMenu();
            }
        };
        mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);

        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            // on first time display view for first nav item
            displayView(0);
        }

        final Context context = getApplicationContext();
        final int duration = Toast.LENGTH_SHORT;
        ImageButton one;

        try {
            one = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imageButton);
            one.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                public void onClick(View v) {


                    final MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(), R.raw.pears);
                    mp.start();

                }
            });
        }
        catch (Exception e){
            Log.d("wshhsounds", Log.getStackTraceString(new Exception()));
        }
    }
```

As requested by @Ryan, heres my layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:padding="0dp" >

    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/imageButton"
        android:src="@drawable/button"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter"
        android:background="@color/white"/>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:background="@color/blue">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/grid_item_label_static"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:text="Pears"
            android:layout_marginTop="3px"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:textSize="50px"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:paddingTop="11dp"
            android:paddingBottom="12dp"/>

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

As requested by @Ryan heres the logcat:

> 03-25 13:57:54.530  13615-13615/com.non.nonabona.sounds
>   E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>       java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.non.nonabona.sounds/com.non.nonabona.sounds.MainActivity}:
>   java.lang.NullPointerException
>               at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2305)
>               at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2359)
>               at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:165)
>               at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1326)
>               at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
>               at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
>               at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5455)
>               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
>               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1187)
>               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1003)
>               at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
>        Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
>               at com.non.nonabona.sounds.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:76)
>               at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5372)
>               at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1104)
>               at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2267)
>               at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2359)
>               at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:165)
>               at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1326)
>               at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
>               at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
>               at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5455)
>               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
>               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1187)
>               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1003)
>               at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

Comment: When you ask a question about an error you are getting, please always make sure to provide the *complete* error text.  Likewise for exceptions, provide the *complete* stack trace.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply use

```
ImageButton one = (ImageButton) findViewByID(R.id.imageButton)
```

in your `onCreate()` method and check your `layout` file if that is proper and have a Button with id `imageButton`

Comment: I looked at my layout file which wasn't the same as where Imagebutton was declared. Hoped it would work when I changed it, but still got the nullpointerException...

Comment: I posted my layout file in the post above

Comment: mDrawerList.setOnItemClickListener(new SlideMenuClickListener());

Comment: So following logcat, the NullPointerException isn't coming from my MediaPlayer, but rather my Navigation Slider menu. Thanks for the help

Answer (score 4):

Do it like

```
ImageButton one = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.imageButton);
```

Comment: Sorry, I shouldve posted my updated code where I tried what you mention: 'one = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.imageButton);'  yet I still get NullPointerException

Comment: Are you doing this code inside `onCreate()` or `onCreateView()`? If yes, try moving your code in `onViewCreated()` method

Comment: Yes I am using this code inside onCreate(). Isn't onViewCreated part of the fragment class? Currently my MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity

Comment: Can you post whole onCreate method?